# OWL's EquivalentClass vs. SubClassOf

Tags: owl

What is the difference between EquivalentClass and SubClass of? While reading through OWL primer, i find the tutorial uses SubClassOf a lot to declare a new class, as follows

```
SubClassOf(
  :Teenager
  DataSomeValuesFrom( :hasAge
    DatatypeRestriction( xsd:integer
      xsd:minExclusive "12"^^xsd:integer
      xsd:maxInclusive "19"^^xsd:integer
    )
  )
)
```

Can I write

```
EquivalentClass(
  :Teenager
  DataSomeValuesFrom( :hasAge
    DatatypeRestriction( xsd:integer
      xsd:minExclusive "12"^^xsd:integer
      xsd:maxInclusive "19"^^xsd:integer
    )
  )
)
```

instead?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When stating that `A` is a *subclass of* `B`, this restricts `A` to necessarily inherit all characteristics of `B`, **but not the other way around**. In your example, `A` = `Teenager`, and `B` = `hasAge [12:19]` (my own notation, but you get the idea).

This means that any instance of `Teenager` in the OWL ontology must necessarily also have the property `hasAge` with a value in the range `[12:19]`, but ***not* the other way around**. Specifically, this does not mean that any instance of something with the property `hasAge` with a value in the range `[12:19]` is also an instance of `Teenager`. To make this clear, consider an instance (called `c`) of class `Car`. We might also say that:

`c . hasAge 13`

This says that instance `c` of `Car` is 13 years old. However, with the subclass axiom defining `Teenager` above, a **reasoner** would **not** infer that `c` is also an instance of `Teenager` (perhaps as we'd want, if teenagers are *people*, not cars).

The difference when using equivalence is that the subclass relationship is implied to go in  **both directions**. So, if we were to instead include the second axiom that defined `Teenager` to be *equivalent* to anything with the property `hasAge` with a value in the range `[12:19]`, then a reasoner would infer that the car `c` is also an instance of `Teenager`.

Answer (score 5):

Equivalent classes might have the same members, e.g.,

```
:USPresident owl:equivalentClass :USCommanderInChief
```

will both have the same individuals (all or some of the US presidents).  So if we assert that John Adams was a USCommanderInChief it can be inferred that John Adams was also a US President.

With subclass, we're indicating a hierarchy.  e.g., GrannySmithApple is a type of Apple.

Answer (score 5):

```
:USPresident owl:equivalentClass :USCommanderInChief .
```

is the same as

```
:USPresident rdfs:subClassOf :USCommanderInChief ;
:USCommanderInChief rdfs:subClassOf :USPresident .
```