# How to express numeric intervals in datatype property in the ontology?

Tags: properties, owl, protege

What I am trying to do is create a datatype property that accepts and recognizes numeric intervals. For example lets say I have the property "temperature". In the ontology I want to create 2 sub properties "hot" and "cold". Hot would be temperatures 20-30 and cold 0-19.
What I am doing at the moment is having some properties set as lowerlim and upperlim. But is there a more convenient way to express intervals directly through the property? So that when I query for example "23" it would recognise its "hot". Any tips?

Thank you in advance

Comment: There's this [teenager example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192435/owls-equivalentclass-vs-subclassof) all around the web. That's one way to do it.

Comment: @scozy I dont really get this example. Using this when you ask for the age 14 for example, will it recognize and provide as output the "teenager"? And this code should be placed in the class expression? Because I am looking a way to do it through the datatype property.

Comment: The OWL 2 specification is pretty clear about that. See [§9.6.6](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Positive_Data_Property_Assertions).

Comment: @user3211165 The answer in that linked question points out that if you say `Teenager subClassOf (hasAge some xsd:integer[> 12, <= 19])`, then it means that if something is a Teenager, then it has such an age, but it *doesn't* mean that everything with such an age is a teenager.  To get the other direction, you'd either need the order reversed, or to use an `equivalentClass` axiom.

Comment: @scozy thank you for your answer. But how do I enter a range of values for an individual/instance. For example I want the instance Meg to have values from 3 to 10 for a specific data property?

Comment: Do you mean you want that `Meg hasAge 3`, and `Meg hasAge 4`, and …, and `Meg hasAge 10`?  That's sort of an unusual thing to want…

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes but not for ages specifically. For ages it does not make sense but for other things it does. Instead of adding everytime has 1, has 2, has 3.. etc is there a way to define to an instance through a data property the numeric values from 2 to 5 for example?

Comment: There's not really an easy way to do that.  If you'll need to do this for multiple individuals, it's probably best to define a class once, e.g., `HasValues2Through5 subClassOf ((hasValue value 2) and (hasValue value 3) and (hasValue value 4) and (hasValue value 5))`, and then say things like `Meg rdf:type HasValues2Through5`.  It's a bit clunky, but I don't know if you can do much better…

Comment: There exist description logics with "fancy" concrete domains. For instance, you could define a role with range Q². [Here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.10.6936) is an interesting survey if you are interested, or just look into temporal description logics. I don't think there is any straightforward way to translate those to any OWL standard, though, without resorting to what you were trying to avoid--double roles and lots of knowledge to maintain consistency.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor  I guess theres no easy way then. I wanted to be able to ask a query about a number and get back as an answer the interval of numbers that belongs to. Doing hasvalue for big intervals is pretty pointless i believe. Thanks though

Answer (score 8):

This is quite straightforward in OWL, however the kind of inferences you're expecting may be a little different to the ones I'll now explain.

In OWL, you can define restrictions on datatype properties (as [I've shown before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192435/owls-equivalentclass-vs-subclassof)).

However, datatype reasoning is required to *infer* that some resource/individual with a *particular datatype value* belongs to some class. Note that not all reasoner implementations support this, however I'll focus on [Pellet](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet), which does.

To demonstrate, I'll create a small OWL ontology. I'll write it out in OWL/XML syntax. It will be long, but hopefully will explain how it's done.

Firstly, define a '[reified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29#RDF_and_OWL)' class called `Temp`:

```xml
<Declaration>
    <Class IRI="#Temp"/>
</Declaration>
```

Next, two sub-classes called `Hot` and `Cold`:

```xml
<Declaration>
    <Class IRI="#Hot"/>
</Declaration>

<SubClassOf>
    <Class IRI="#Hot"/>
    <Class IRI="#Temp"/>
</SubClassOf>

<Declaration>
    <Class IRI="#Cold"/>
</Declaration>

<SubClassOf>
    <Class IRI="#Cold"/>
    <Class IRI="#Temp"/>
</SubClassOf>
```

Now, we can define our datatype property, called `tempDegC`:

```xml
<Declaration>
    <DataProperty IRI="#tempDegC"/>
</Declaration>
```

I'll also create a couple of individuals which use this property, as follows:

```xml
<Declaration>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#x"/>
</Declaration>

<DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataProperty IRI="#tempDegC"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#x"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;double">13.5</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>

<Declaration>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#y"/>
</Declaration>

<DataPropertyAssertion>
    <DataProperty IRI="#tempDegC"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#y"/>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;double">23.4</Literal>
</DataPropertyAssertion>
```

**Note that I haven't asserted which class `x` or `y` belong to**, just that they have `tempDegC` of certain `xsd:double` values.

If we asked a reasoner to classify the ontology at this point, we wouldn't see any new inferences.

What we want is for the reasoner to automatically infer that `x` belongs to class `Cold`, and that `y` belongs to class `Hot`.

We can achieve this by restricting the *definition* of the classes `Cold` and `Hot` in terms of the datatype property `tempDegC`, as follows:

```xml
<EquivalentClasses>
    <Class IRI="#Cold"/>
    <DataSomeValuesFrom>
        <DataProperty IRI="#tempDegC"/>
        <DatatypeRestriction>
            <Datatype abbreviatedIRI="xsd:double"/>
            <FacetRestriction facet="&xsd;maxInclusive">
                <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;double">19.0</Literal>
            </FacetRestriction>
        </DatatypeRestriction>
    </DataSomeValuesFrom>
</EquivalentClasses>
```

Here, this axiom defines `Cold` as *"**any** instance which has a `tempDegC` with a `xsd:double` value which is `<= 19`"*.

Similarly, we can restrict `Hot` as follows:

```xml
<EquivalentClasses>
    <Class IRI="#Hot"/>
    <DataSomeValuesFrom>
        <DataProperty IRI="#tempDegC"/>
        <DatatypeRestriction>
            <Datatype abbreviatedIRI="xsd:double"/>
            <FacetRestriction facet="&xsd;maxInclusive">
                <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;double">30.0</Literal>
            </FacetRestriction>
            <FacetRestriction facet="&xsd;minExclusive">
                <Literal datatypeIRI="&xsd;double">19.0</Literal>
            </FacetRestriction>
        </DatatypeRestriction>
    </DataSomeValuesFrom>
</EquivalentClasses>
```

Here, this axiom defines `Hot` as *"**any** instance which has a `tempDegC` with a `xsd:double` value which is `> 19`  and `<= 30`"*.

Now, with these definitions, asking the reasoner to classify the ontology infers two new  statements:

`x : Cold`

`y : Hot`

**Explanation**

A key to obtaining these inferences was the use of `EquivalentClasses` to define the restriction on `Cold` and `Hot` classes. By using `EquivalentClasses` instead of `SubClassOf`, we're saying that *anything* with a `tempdegC` within the specified ranges belongs in the class.

If, however, we were to instead use `SubClassOf` in defining the restriction on `Cold` and `Hot` classes above, this would only restrict instances of `Cold` and `Hot` to abide by the constraint, a so-called *necessary* condition, in that it is necessary for all instances to abide by the restriction.

In contrast, `EquivalentClasses` defines both *necessary* and so-called *sufficient* conditions: not only must all instances (necessarily) abide by the restriction, but it is *sufficient* that if *any* individual (such as `x` or `y`) meet the restrictions, that they are also members. It is this *sufficient* condition which the reasoner uses to infer that `x : Cold` and `y : Hot`.

A link to the [full example ontology is here](http://pastebin.com/sjs3tRU8). Try loading it into [Protege](http://protege.stanford.edu/) and classify it using the [Pellet reasoner plugin](https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/tree/master/protege/plugin).

Note that I tried classifying this ontology with [HermiT](http://hermit-reasoner.com/) and [FaCT++](http://owl.man.ac.uk/factplusplus/) which otherwise failed to produce the inferences, throwing exceptions, indicating they do not support such datatype reasoning.