# why inference is not working well

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, rdfs

I have two ontologies which i join them together in one big ontology

This is in the big ontology

```
  <!-- http://www.MusicSemanticOntology/mso#r1 -->

    <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.MusicSemanticOntology/mso#r1">
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
        <rs:about rdf:resource="http://music.org/musicontology/mo#5th_Symphony"/>
        <rs:createdOn rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">1956-06-25T04:00:00-05:00</rs:createdOn>
        <rs:ratesBy rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1.0</rs:ratesBy>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

as you see, the instance r1 is from Rangs and it has createdOn and has ratesBy predicate

I have this class:

```
<!-- http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Likes -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Likes">
    <rdfs:subClassOf>
        <owl:Class>
            <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#Rates"/>
                <owl:Class>
                    <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy"/>
                            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.8</owl:hasValue>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy"/>
                            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">0.9</owl:hasValue>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                        <owl:Restriction>
                            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://semanticrecommender.com/rs#ratesBy"/>
                            <owl:hasValue rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">1.0</owl:hasValue>
                        </owl:Restriction>
                    </owl:unionOf>
                </owl:Class>
            </owl:intersectionOf>
        </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:subClassOf>
</owl:Class>
```

why the r1 is not being form class likes when i run the reaonsoner? though the value of its rangeBy is 1 and it has the relattion about, and it has the un mandatory createdOn predicate and the value of about (which is the 5th_syphony) is from type `Recommendable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't infer that `r1` is of type `Likes` because it does not have sufficient information to do so.

You have defined your class `Likes` as a *subclass* of your restrictions. This means that you have defined *necessary* conditions for class membership (that is, *if* something is an instance of `Likes`, *then* it must have the necessary property values), but you haven't defined that these conditions are also *sufficient* (that is, *if* something has these property values, *then* it must be an instance of `Likes`). It is perfectly valid for something to have the specified `ratesBy` values and yet not be an instance of the `Likes` class. A fix for this is to define it as an `owl:equivalentClass` instead of a `rdfs:subClassOf`.