# OWL subClassOf restrictions: why use them?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, semantics, inference

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192435/owls-equivalentclass-vs-subclassof) provides a good explanation of the semantic difference between `rdfs:subClassOf` and `owl:equivalentClass`.

In the example provided by the OP, the class `:Teenager` is declared to be a subclass of a data property restriction on the `:hasAge` property with a value in the range [12:19]. The answer states that the `rdfs:subClassOf` assertion

> means that any instance of Teenager in the OWL ontology must necessarily also have the property hasAge with a value in the range [12:19].

Although this statement may capture the semantics of subclass restrictions in OWL, what is the ultimate value of using them? It seems that not much can be inferred, programmatically, from a subclass restriction. So, is its main utility to document semantic modeling intent? When defining restrictions, why would an ontologist *prefer* `rdfs:subClassOf` over `owl:equivalentClass`?

For example, I encoded the following ontology (in Protégé 5.6.1), based on the OP's example:

```
@prefix : <urn:test/> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <urn:test/> .

[ rdf:type owl:Ontology
 ] .

#################################################################
#    Data properties
#################################################################

###  urn:test/hasAge
:hasAge rdf:type owl:DatatypeProperty ;
        rdfs:label "has age" .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  urn:test/Person
:Person rdf:type owl:Class ;
        rdfs:label "Person" .


###  urn:test/Teenager
:Teenager rdf:type owl:Class ;
          rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Person
                                                 [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                                                   owl:onProperty :hasAge ;
                                                   owl:someValuesFrom [ rdf:type rdfs:Datatype ;
                                                                        owl:onDatatype xsd:integer ;
                                                                        owl:withRestrictions ( [ xsd:minInclusive 12
                                                                                               ]
                                                                                               [ xsd:maxInclusive 19
                                                                                               ]
                                                                                             )
                                                                      ]
                                                 ]
                                               ) ;
                            rdf:type owl:Class
                          ] ;
          rdfs:label "Teenager" .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  urn:test/_car
:_car rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
      :hasAge 13 .


###  urn:test/_chris
:_chris rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
                 :Teenager ;
        :hasAge 20 ;
        rdfs:label "Chris" .
```

When I run a reasoner (e.g., HermiT), the individual `:_chris` is still inferred to be a member of the `:Teenager` class, as asserted, even though the value of `:hasAge` is outside the defined range--and the ontology is not inferred to be inconsistent (I assume this is due to the Open World Assumption). `:_chris` is also inferred to be a member of the `:Person` class--and that's it.

If I run a DL Query in Protégé with the expression `'has age' some xsd:integer[>= 12 , <= 19]`, it *does* return `:Teenager` as a subclass and `:_chris` and `:_car` as instances.

Changing the DL query to `'has age' some xsd:integer[>= 12 , <= 42]` returns the same results, whereas changing it to `'has age' some xsd:integer[>= 13 , <= 42]` removes `:Teenager` as a subclass. So, that's interesting. Beyond DL queries, are there other standard ways (with current tooling) to leverage a restriction defined with `rdfs:subClassOf` in OWL?

Ultimately, if my main interest is in deriving new statements based on inferencing and OWL axioms, does a subclass restriction really give me anything of value?

Comment: It's not being inconsistent because all you express is that there is at least one value for age being between 12 and 19. if you want to make be the only possible range for any age value, you have to append the "only" restriction as well: `and ('has age' only xsd:integer[>= 12 , <= 19])`

Comment: reagrding subclass in general, indeed, not all things on the right hand side will be shown during inference, because there would infinite many. For atomic classes this is trivial, things like `'has age' value 42'` would also be something that can be considered a fact with a concrete value which is finite. But for restrictions like "well it has some age between X and Y" it can't show up in the Protege editor, because you wouldn't know which age. BY the way, OWL axioms can also be considered as a tool for documentation of your domain, which is also helpful.

Comment: For stronger constraint, I'd suggest to use so-called shapes, e.g. SHACL or SHeX

Comment: @UninformedUser, thanks for your comments! Happy to accept if you’d like to post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although this statement may capture the semantics of subclass restrictions in OWL, what is the ultimate value of using them? It seems that not much can be inferred, programmatically, from a subclass restriction.

What can be inferred is precisely what the subclass states. If you have this definition:

```
:Teenager a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Person
    [ a owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty :hasAge ;
      owl:someValuesFrom [ a rdfs:Datatype ;
        owl:onDatatype xsd:integer ;
        owl:withRestrictions (
          [ xsd:minInclusive 12 ]
          [ xsd:maxInclusive 19 ]
        )
      ]
    ]
  ) ; a owl:Class ] .
```

Then a statement `:_chris a :Teenager` implies both `:_chris a :Person` and

```
:_chris :hasAge [ a [ a rdfs:Datatype ; # a bit incorrect since literal is treated as an object here 
  owl:onDatatype xsd:integer ;
  owl:withRestrictions (
    [ xsd:minInclusive 12 ]
    [ xsd:maxInclusive 19 ]
  )
] ] .
```

Now you are correct that this does not give you any new interesting triples (since there are 8 concrete alternatives), but it *could* warn you against inconsistencies. The reason it does not in this case is because *a person can have multiple ages*, or at least you don't impose anything stricter in your ontology. Your ontology states that only *some* (hence `owl:someValuesFrom`) ages of a person have to be between 12 and 19 for a teenager, but not all of them! Once you add `:_chris :hasAge 20`, there is no inconsistency in that, since it is still possible Chris may have another age that is within the boundaries (indeed he can have *all* 8 ages) ‒ this is the open-world assumption.

Now I believe the issue here is the pattern of your restriction. This kind of pattern would be more suited for something like nationality:

```
:British a owl:Class ;
  rdfs:subClassOf [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Person
    [ a owl:Restriction ;
      owl:onProperty :hasCitizenship ;
      owl:someValuesFrom :BritishCitizenship
    ]
  ) ; a owl:Class ] .
```

Though perhaps imprecise in meaning, it would be reasonable to follow this pattern for this kind of class, more than for the age group.

There are two ways to "fix" the ontology in order to be able to detect the inconsistency:

- Declare `:hasAge a owl:FunctionalProperty`. A functional property has exactly one value, and so having multiple ages is an inconsistency. This makes sense to use in this situation.
- Use `owl:allValuesFrom` instead of `owl:someValuesFrom`. This is not as restrictive as the first option, but it still prevents you from stating conflicting facts about the age group of a person.

I would use both solutions, since they both state the intent of the ontology closer to the domain logic.

---

Now for the titular question, this is actually unrelated to the issue in your ontology, and simply depends on how accurate you want your ontology to be in relation to the business objects. The two questions to ask here are:

- If someone is a teenager, do they have age between 12 and 19? (Negation: Could someone be a teenager and *not* have age between 12 and 19?)
- If a person has age between 12 and 19, is it a teenager? (Negation: Could a person have age between 12 and 19 and *not* be a teenager?)

I think that, for this case, if one is true, the other should be true as well, in which case `owl:equivalentClass` would be a better choice for the class relation, and for any other *definition* like this one. All in all, you shouldn't necessarily prefer *either of* `rdfs:subClassOf` or `owl:equivalentClass` for its own sake, instead you should pick the one that is closer to the real-world relations of the objects you try to describe, within the limits of how strict you want your ontology to be.